# Unable to pass job IDs to SLURM

Tags: bash, hpc, slurm

I would like to submit a sequence of dependent jobs to our `SLURM` cluster using job IDs. I tried the following script, as suggested in [this link](https://hpc.nih.gov/docs/job_dependencies.html).

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --time 12:00:00
#SBATCH --nodes 9
#SBATCH --tasks-per-node 40
#SBATCH -p standard

    # first job - no dependencies

    jid1=$(sbatch prod1.sh)

    # subsequent jobs with dependencies

    jid2=$(sbatch --dependency=afterok:$jid1 prod2.sh)
```

Although the first job ran, the subsequent ones did not. I received the following error:

```
sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Job dependency problem
```

Could someone please let me know the error in this script? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use the option "--parsable" to get only the jobid.

For example:

jid1=$(sbatch --parsable prod1.sh)